# Url didn't match any routes in react-router

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router

I am using Express and React to build an isomorphic app. I want to use react for a series url with fixed path like: `hostname/admin/xxx`, `hostname/admin/yyy`, `hostname/admin/zzz`.

In Express the router is:

```
// in server.js file
app.use('/admin', admin);

// in admin.js router file
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match()  // react-router's match method
}
```

and in the `react-router`'s `routes` file it is:

```
<Route path='/' component={Admin}>
    <Route path='child' component={Child} />
</Route>
```

When I visit `hostname/admin`, the server rendering can match the routes exactly, but the browser thrown an error: `Warning: [react-router] Location "/admin" did not match any routes`.

If I change the `routes` to

```
<Route path='/admin' component={Admin}>
    <Route path='child' component={Child} />
</Route>
```

the server rendering cannot match any routes.

I think the problem is, for server rendering, the `path` is `'/'`, but for client it is `'/admin'`. How can I fix it except using `app.use('/', admin)` in Express?

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is add `'/admin'` to the `location` property in `match()` method:

```
match({
    routes,
    location: '/admin' + req.url
  }, (error, redirectLocation, props) => {
});
```